# calculator a- add symbol from array on each digit

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, calculator, symbols, digits

```
var switchBox = "num_txt1";
var signSwitcher = "";
var minNum = Math.max(900000)
var maxNum = Math.max(999999)
num_txt1.border = false;
num_txt2.border = false;
num_txt1.restrict = "0-9";
num_txt2.restrict = "0-9";
var fish:Object = new Object;
```

Array:

```
var onesArray: Array = [fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4, fish5, fish6, fish7, fish8, fish9];
var tensArray: Array = [fish10, fish20, fish30, fish40, fish50, fish60, fish70, fish80, fish90];
var hundredsArray: Array = [fish100, fish200, fish300, fish400, fish500, fish600, fish700, fish800, fish900];
var thousandsArray: Array = [fish1k, fish2k, fish3k, fish4k, fish5k, fish6k, fish7k, fish8k, fish9k];
var tenthousandsArray: Array = [fish10k, fish20k, fish30k, fish40k, fish50k, fish60k, fish70k, fish80k, fish90k];
var hundredthousandsArray: Array = [fish100k, fish200k, fish300k, fish400k, fish500k, fish600k, fish700k, fish800k, fish900k];
var millionsArray: Array = [fish1m, fish2m, fish3m, fish4m, fish5m, fish6m, fish7m, fish8m, fish9m];
```

Buttons (e.g. 1 and 2):

```
num1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1Click);
function btn1Click(event) {
    if (switchBox == "num_txt1" && num_txt1.text.length < 6) {
        var val1 = num_txt1.text;
        num_txt1.text = val1 + "1";
            fish = onesArray[0];
            onesArray[0].x = 306.05;
            onesArray[0].y = 56.05;
            var sfish: FishOpening = new FishOpening();
            sfish.play();
    }
    else if (num_txt2.text.length < 6) {
        var val2 = num_txt2.text;
        num_txt2.text = val2 + "1";
    }
}

num2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn2Click);
function btn2Click(event) {
    if (switchBox == "num_txt1" && num_txt1.text.length < 6) 
        {
        var val1 = num_txt1.text;
        num_txt1.text = val1 + "2";
        }
    else if (num_txt2.text.length < 6) 
        {
        var val2 = num_txt2.text;
        num_txt2.text = val2 + "2";
        }
}
```

Each digit will be displayed the number of fishes as a symbol from an array when one of the numbers is pressed. There are 6 digits, ones to millions from left to right.

Comment: You did not ask a question... What is the problem you are trying to fix? What did you try that is almost working (maybe we can fix it)?... For example: If user has put number **735** then what is the problem for your code to handle this 735 number?

Comment: PS: Show the pictures for **fish8**, **fish20** and **fish4k**... It's possible your calculator needs to know about the "zero" symbol. Normally you only need 10 digits `0 up to 9` to write any other number. Here you are using "fishes" for **4k** and **5m**, it's confusing so show us a picture of how it looks.

Comment: It's not fixing, it's to solve how to display the number of fish Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYAqVebFC6c (4:52 - 6:53) & https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F_S3mmJrN_y5h879lYuzS9209zkKakxb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are still **not saying anything**. You say _"How to display the number of fish?"_ but before that you said _"Each digit will be displayed the number of fishes as a symbol from an array when one of the numbers is pressed. There are 6 digits, ones to millions from left to right."_... **OK** you know **what you have to do** so which part of that is the problem? Did you create the digits for the "numbers" and add a click listener (for your when "number is pressed")? If user presses button for **fish10k**, what happens if you try to add to Stage a fish from the Array?

Comment: No, I haven't created the digits for the numbers. Any ideas for this code to solve this question to create the digits for the "numbers"?

Comment: After `fish = onesArray[0];` what does it say if you add a trace? Like `trace( "fish is : " + fish);`... Also do you know what the `addChild( );` command does?

Comment: AddChild(); is to add a child display object, such as a component, to a container as part of a view state. The trace says: "fish is : [class fish1]"; There is an error: 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: Try setting as `var fish : MovieClip = new MovieClip();` then try adding to screen as `addChild( fish );` ... Does it now show a fish on screen? Does it solve your _"How to display the number of fish"_ question?

Comment: Not yet. There are another 2 errors: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.; TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fish1$ to flash.display.MovieClip.; I want to display it on the stage, not in a textfield.

Comment: Any ideas how to solve these?

Comment: No idea. **(1)** Stream and IO errors are usually from some file loading. Look at your shown code. It is not doing anything to cause such Stream error. **(2)** I thought `fish1` was a visual thing (is a Bitmap, or is a Sprite, or is a MovieClip) that's why I suggested adding as movieclip. If it cannot be converted then I don't what you did here when you say _"Each digit will be displayed the number of fishes as a symbol from an array"_. What "symbol" is in the array and do you think it can be displayed on Stage as pixels? What kind of thing (its data type) is `fish1`?

Comment: They are all Movieclips and exported for Actionscript linkage.

Comment: But you didn't say what the AS linkage name is called. If it's called `fish1` then try as `var fish : fish1= new fish1();` then later do `addChild (fish)` does `fish1` Movieclip now show on the Stage? It might help to practice by making a simple test project where you check if your code can add something from library to stage. Then when working, try to do it from Array (where the array itself holds variable of library item,)

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll let you know it is working or not.

Comment: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
 at FishCalculator_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[FishCalculator_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:25]
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fish1$ to fish1.
 at FishCalculator_fla::MainTimeline/btn1Click()[FishCalculator_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:665]

Comment: There are 2 errors, I have set the linkage all the number of fishes and there are filled in a different arrays, any ideas how to fix these?